# Shortcuts not working

Tags: shortcut-keys, shortcuts

Contorl + Alt + T for terminal is not working after the most recent update.

I am very new to Ubuntu, so I am not sure what to do.

Are there any solutions for this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

the first thing you could do is to check the shortcut settings.
It's in the **System Settings** -> **Keyboard** -> **Shortcuts**
[image: Shortcuts]
Make sure it's still assigned to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>

And the second thing is to check the hardware, make sure these keys are working.

Answer (score -1):

You can open the terminal and type

```
killall gnome-keyring-daemon
```

this will restart the daemon and your shortcut should work. I don't know why this is necessary but it is. I also would recommend doing this after every system restart because you need to do this fix after every single boot. 
To do this go to the autostart menu (the exact name might vary) and add this command. 
After doing this it should work, at least it did work on my PC.